# Ideas on logic/algorithm and how to prevent race in threaded writes to SqlServer

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, sql-server-2005

I have the following logic:

```
public void InQueueTable(DataTable Table)
{
    int incomingRows = Table.Rows.Count;

    if (incomingRows >= RowsThreshold)
    {
        // asyncWriteRows(Table)

        return;
    }

    if ((RowsInMemory + incomingRows) >= RowsThreshold)
    {
        // copy and clear internal table
        // asyncWriteRows(copyTable)
    }

    internalTable.Merge(Table);
}
```

There is one problem with this lagorithm:

- Given `RowsThreshold = 10000`
- If `incomingRows` puts `RowsInMemory`
  over `RowsThreshold`: (1)
  asynchronously write out data, (2)
  merge incoming data
- If `incomingRows` *is* over
  `RowsThreshold`, asynchronously write
  incoming data

**But what if???**  Assume a second thread spins up and calls asyncWriteRows(xxxTable); also, that each thread owning the asynchronous method will be writing to the same table in SqlServer: ***Does SqlServer handle this sort of multi-threaded write functionality to the same table?***

**Follow up**
Based on Greg D's suggestion:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, 
                                              sqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
{
    // perform bulkcopy
}
```

Regardless, I still have the issue of signaling the asyncWriteRows(copyTable). The algorithm needs to determine the need to go ahead and copy internalTable, clear internalTable, and asyncWriteRows(copyTable). I think that what I need to do is move the `internalTable.Copy()` call to it's own method:

```
private DataTable CopyTable (DataTable srcTable)
{
    lock (key)
    {
        return srcTable.Copy();
    }
}
```

...and then the following changes to the InQueue method:

```
public void InQueueTable(DataTable Table)
{
    int incomingRows = Table.Rows.Count;

    if (incomingRows >= RowsThreshold)
    {
        // asyncWriteRows(Table)

        return;
    }

    if ((RowsInMemory + incomingRows) >= RowsThreshold)
    {
        // copy and clear internal table
        // asyncWriteRows(CopyTable(Table))
    }

    internalTable.Merge(Table);
}
```

...finally, add a callback method:

```
private void WriteCallback(Object iaSyncResult)
{
    int rowCount = (int)iaSyncResult.AsyncState;

    if (RowsInMemory >= rowCount)
    {
        asyncWriteRows(CopyTable(internalTable));
    }
}
```

This is what I have determined as a solution. Any feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't use transactions?

Comment: I have a feeling that's what a DBA would ask me to do. We don't have the luxury of a DBA in our shop.

Comment: I haven't done anything with transactions yet, so I guess there is no time like the present to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit now that I'm not an expert in this field.

With transactions and cursors you will get lock escalation if your operation is large. E.g. your operation will start locking a row, then a page then a table if it needs to, preventing other operations from functioning.
The idiot that I was assumed that SQL Server would just queue these blocked operations up and wait for locks to be released, but it just returns errors and it's up to the API programmer to keep retrying (someone correct me if I'm wrong, or if it's fixed in a later version).
If you are happy to be reading possibly old data that you then copy over, like we were, we changed our isolation mode to stop the server blocking operations unnecessarily. 
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;

You may also alter your insert statments to use NOLOCK. But please read up on this.

Comment: You say someone correct me if I'm wrong so happy to oblige! SQL Server will indeed wait indefinitely for locks to be released (unless a deadlock occurs when it will kill one of the processes) There is a lock timeout option you can set though. Maybe you encountered this? Also ADO.NET etc have a connection timeout that defaults to 30 seconds.

Comment: @Dr: I am planning on a transactional BulkCopy. MSDN says that if an overwrite from one transaction occurs, that transaction will roll back. I will have to check an see if I get a response when a transaction gets rolled back so I can try again.

Comment: @Martin I think Connection timeout is just for connecting, whereas QueryTimeout is for execution and is set per HSTMT (I use ODBC- Old school I know). I was definatley not experiencing any queuing behaviour, but I think i was getting deadlock attempting to read while another operation was writing (not similar to the OP's problem).

Comment: @Dr Giles - Yes you're correct. I should have put `CommandTimeout` for ADO.NET