# Queued execution of threads in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a windows service which executes a job asynchronously every few minutes, sometimes the windows service executes and the previous job has not finished, using threading is there a way to queue the new job if the previous one hasnt finished so that it starts running when the first job finishes?

Comment: Sounds like you would have to be careful not to get an infinitely growing backlog of tasks if they are being queued faster than they can complete. Make sure a max number to queue is present somewhere (for example just one!) or just take the easy way out and prevent a new job starting if an old one is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own producer/consumer queue of jobs - effectively a single-thread threadpool.

This is easy to do in .NET 4 using [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx); before then it's a *little* trickier, but not *too* bad.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using 3.5 do you have a link to an example in 3.5? thanks

Comment: @ryudice: There's some sample code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228

Comment: @Jon: With 3.5, should the OP use Task Parallel Lib, check `cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested` and store task in Queue<T> or List<T> is the task is currently busy?

Comment: @IAbstract: How would the OP use the Task Parallel Library from 3.5? I know that Reactive Extensions comes with *some* of the TPL, but not all of it as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Jon: I was under the impression that TPL was available for 3.5 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/02/8567802.aspx

Comment: @IAbstract: That's a CTP. Not a full release you should rely on in production. Note the bit in blue on that page - the CTP is no longer available, and the subset which is part of Parallel Extensions is unsupported.

Comment: @Jon: ah...I'm glad I didn't try to take someone's advice about trying to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555307/enabling-queuet-with-concurrency/4555395#4555395

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the queue in main controlling service.
on the completion of thread and/or periodicaly you can check queue and start next task.