# System.Threading.dll makes WPF application start in more than 30 seconds

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, windows-embedded, concurrent-queue

A "completely empty" WPF application project targetting framework 3.5 takes more than 30 seconds to start on Windows 7 embedded SP1.

The problem doesn't appear on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 neither on Windows XP.

The only thing in the WPF project is a declaration/initialization of a ConcurrentQueue coming from System.Threading.dll:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<String> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

I had to use this dll because the ConcurrentQueue doesn't exist in the 3.5 framework.

This seems like a system issue, could this be a problem between the two ConcurrentQueue? The one in my dll and the one in the framework 4.0 installed on the Windows 7 embedded computer?

**Some relevant information**

The System.Threading dll's version is 1.0.2856.102

**Edit**

As suggested by @Sinatr I created another ConcurrentQueue (copy paste of ConcurrentQueue, SystemCollectionsConcurrent_ProducerConsumerCollectionDebugView and IProducerConsumerCollection with ILSpy).

This solves the problem but I would like to know why.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That's what I thought, the problem I face made me doubt it

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'll install Visual Studio on this computer to check this.

Comment: This sounds like a hack: your project is targeting 3.5, but you are adding (via references?) dll containing `ConcurrentQueue` from 4.0. Maybe you should not do that, but rather simply implement it yourself? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4555307/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr This is a good point but concurrency is a very complicated matter. I probably shouldn't try to implement it myself, I'll try to decompile System.Threading.dll using ILSpy and rename the collection. But knowing what exactly causes the problem would be interesting

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable the fetching of symbols.
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> uncheck `Microsoft Symbol Servers`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's already unchecked (default is probably unchecked because I don't remember ever changing it)