# Yielding with an IDisposable resource

Tags: c#, yield-return

Is there a proper way to yield through a disposable resource? The returned objects are IDisposable, but the element it is iterating through is.

Here is an example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Fetch(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    using (var client = new CouchbaseClient())
    {
        yield return ids.Select(s => s.ToString());
    }
}
```

Right now, calling this would not dispose the `using` resource obtained. I know I can just to a ToList and return it all at once, but is there a way to handle this "properly", or do I have to keep a tab on the IDisposable resource and dispose of it manually when I'm done?

Comment: Isn't it responsability of the one going to iterate over the resource to dispose when it is done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2274664/34397

Comment: @ArthurNunes I suspect so, but I'm just curious if the language offers anything for this or if I have to do it by hand (likely by making the containing class IDisposable and moving disposing logic there).

Comment: @SLaks Very interesting question; glad I read it, but not sure how relevant it is to this question.  Was there a comment or sub-point discussed there that I missed?  Clearly the marked answer yields from a `using`, and nobody calls it out as bad, but nobody explains that it's okay (or why it's okay) as far as I could tell.

Comment: Could you fix your code so that it compiles? Right now, you're yielding a collection, so the return type would be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. I assume that's not what you meant.

Comment: See the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2274773/34397.  `yield`ing from `using` is a bad idea, becasue callers that don't `Dispose()` the enumerator will mess you up.

Comment: @svick It's not what I meant, but it was purely an example, and inconsequential to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, you don't need to worry about it as long as the caller of the method handles the `IEnumerator` objects properly.

`IEnumerator` implementes `IDisposable`, and the logic used in creating the iterator blocks is actually smart enough to execute all un-executed finally blocks when it is disposed.  A finally block is created as a result of the `using` call, and that is where the `IDisposable` resource is disposed.

So as long as the `IEnumerator` objects created from this `IEnumerable` are either iterated fully (in which case the final `MoveNext` call will reach the end of the `using` block and dispose of the resource) or disposed the `IDisposable` client will be disposed.

Note that if you're concerned the user of your code may not treat the `IEnumerator` objects properly then you're best bet is to not use an iterator block with lazy evaluation.  If you want to ensure that even if the caller doesn't "play nice" then eagerly evaluate the method (i.e. take the code you have, dump the results into a list, and then return that list).  If the consequences of not disposing the resource are primarily, or entirely performance related (not releasing some memory for a while longer, keeping open a connection, etc.) then it may not be a concern, but if holding onto the lock forever is a major problem (i.e. a locked resource that could result in deadlocks if not released) then the advantage of lazy evaluation may not be worth it.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood how the yield handled `using`, I didn't realize it would open it each time, which is not at all what I want, but it does answer my question. I'll just solve the problem by creating an instance of my base class when I need it.

Comment: @DmitryStarosta Iterator blocks weren't intorduced until .NET 2.0, so the question doesn't even apply to earlier versions.

Comment: @AndrewKoester It doesn't open it each time; it opens it once when you ask for the first item, and it closes it when you either ask for the last item or dispose of the `IEnumerator`.  As I said, if it's absolutely 100% imperative that the resource be disposed, don't do this.  If it's generally best, but the world won't end if the code using this doesn't play nice, then it's fine.